# NHibernate Conceptual Aggregate Roots

Tags: nhibernate, architecture

I have a couple of entities that I want to treat as an aggregate.  The problem is their association is conceptual rather than via foreign keys in the DB.

The schema I was given:
[image]
<sub>(source: [robtennyson.us](http://files.robtennyson.us/2009/2009-04-17_1414.png))</sub>

My goal is to create an `InventoryWeek` class that I add inventory transactions to.  So the inventory week obviously wraps `FACIL_INVENTORY_WEEK` and the transactions are added to `FACIL_INVENTORY`. So pulling this from the DB, I would get the week given the facility and date, and then I would want all of the transactions that have an `INVENTORY_DATE` within the week.

**Is there a way to map this relationship in nhibernate? Or is there a better way to model this altogether?**

Comment: I read it several time and i still don't understand the problem. You should probably make it more general, not specific for your domain, that it is easier to understand for people not knowing your domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can map relations between tables based on non-primary-keys, but in a limited way.

To give some specific advise, you have to ask a more specific question. Try to map it and if something does not work as you expect, ask.